# Need help displaying images from mysql to webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have stored images in phpmyadmin in a BLOB format. When I try to display them on my webpage, weird symbols and letters show up. The pictures are a mix of jog and png. Please help.

Here is the code that I currently have.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbConn.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  header("Location: clientLogin.php");
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM ip_games ";

$stmt = $dbConn->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();


?> 

<style>

body {
background-color: grey;
}

table {

         margin: 0 auto;
    }

td {
         padding-right: 30px;
    }

</style>

<html>
<body>
  <div>
      <form action="welcome.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign out" />
      </form>  
 </div>

     <h1>Happy Face Emoji Games</h1>

     <form>
        Name: <?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?> <br />
      </form>

<table>

         <?
for ($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++)
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $result[$i]["picture"] . "<br />" . $result[$i]["name"]. " <br /> " .$result[$i]["console"] . " <br />" . "$" . $result[$i]["cost"] . "</td>";
//echo "<td>".$result[$i]["console"]."</td>";
//echo "<td>".$result[$i]["description"]."</td>";
//echo "<td>".$result[$i]["cost"]."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason that you decided to keep picture in MySQL rather than just store path reference to the pictures?  For most use cases, this would be the preferable approach.

Comment: Ya, don't you dare save that image in the database

Comment: @MikeBrant I'd assume it's because he doesn't know what he's doing. AKA Why he even mentioned phpmyadmin in this thread :p PHPMyAdmin is a gui tool to deal with MySQL... it's not MySQL :p

Comment: Use the <img src> before displaying the image...

Comment: Yup, I have no idea what I'm doing haha. My professor wants us to use phpmyadmin for almost everything

Comment: Your professor is hopefully just trying to make it easier for you. In the real world (if you ever work for like a amazon or ticketmaster or grubhub or etc etc) we don't use phpmyadmin :p It won't be a hard transition as long as you pay attention to the SQL queries that are issued as a result of what you type in their interface. Just friendly advice ;) best of luck sir

Comment: @skrilled haha thank you for the advice! I would use local but I have the for loop for database and I don't know how I would insert each and every picture (I do have pictures in a folder as well as url image links) because I have to update and delete. I felt it was better to include the pictures in the database so that when I deleted or updated, it would execute without me doing any more manual work in the database.

Comment: It's better practice to not truly delete things either. Laws require you to keep data for several years in the business world, so when some company tells you your account is deleted they really just updated some is_deleted type column from 0 to 1 and they exclude anything with a 1 from being accessible and etc ;p That type of practice is good for being able to revert major f' ups too :)

Comment: I got the code to work. You guys are amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your image in an `<img>` tag.

```
<img src="<?php echo $result[$i]["picture"]; ?>" />
```

Give that a try and let me know :).

Edit: I wrote that as if it was in the page, for your question you probably want:

```
echo "<td><img src='" . $result[$i]["picture"] . "' />" . "<br />"... etc.
```

Comment: As an after thought though you would probably be better storing the URL to some sort of CDN in your database. Then you could simply pull the image URL from the DB and it will be served by the CDN.

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $result[$i]["picture"]; ?>" />

Comment: Sorry my bad! Thanks zeflex :)

Comment: also, don't miss the comma ;

Comment: @zeflex It still gives me the random symbols and a broken image image

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the format of the data - have you tried this approach with the uri in Jaan's answer below?

Answer (score 1):

To directly use the binary data as a an image source, you can use the data URI scheme, for example:

```
$uri = 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row['binary-data']);
```

This URI can then be used directly as the image’s source:

```
background-image: url(<?php echo $uri; ?>)
<img src="<?php echo $uri; ?>">
```

not good practice, older browser issues, load issues and catching issues. cheer

Comment: where ever your image tag is.

Comment: i get a syntax error. I don't know to proper format for the code you suggested